# Getting Error "No best type found for implicitly-typed array" using LINQ and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5

```
var allCategories = _db.Categories;
var result = from c in allCategories
             select new[] { c.CategoryID, c.Name, c.SortOrder};
```

when i use `select new {...};` but i get result as object array.

But when i try to use `select new[] {...};` i get the following error.

```
No best type found for implicitly-typed array
```

Below is my complete Method of Controller.

```
public ActionResult Index(jQueryDataTableParamModel param=null)
{

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest() && param!=null)
    {
        var allCategories = _db.Categories;
        var result = from c in allCategories
                     select new[] { c.CategoryID, c.Name, c.SortOrder};

        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = allCategories.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = allCategories.Count(),
            aaData = result
        },
                        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return View();
}
```

If i am doing wrong way please guide me to right path as i am new to ASP.NET MVC.

---

**Update:**

I am getting JSON Array like this:

```
{"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":3,"iTotalDisplayRecords":3,"aaData":[{"CategoryID":1,"Name":"Computers","SortOrder":1},{"CategoryID":2,"Name":"Laptops","SortOrder":1},{"CategoryID":3,"Name":"Mobiles","SortOrder":1}]}
```

where as i want Json Array like this

```
{"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":3,"iTotalDisplayRecords":3,"aaData":[["CategoryID":1,"Name":"Computers","SortOrder":1],["CategoryID":2,"Name":"Laptops","SortOrder":1],["CategoryID":3,"Name":"Mobiles","SortOrder":1]]}
```

The reason behind this is datatables is not showing data in grid, so i guess this is the reason behind not showing data. As i am getting the array like the second one in PHP and datatables works fine over there.

---

**Update: 2**

I Just Tried like this,

```
select new [] { Convert.ToString(c.CategoryID), c.Name, Convert.ToString(c.SortOrder)};
```

as everything will become string. but now after this error is gone i am not getting the error relating to converting of string.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

Comment: You are getting the error because you are trying to mix strings and integers in an implictly typed array, and there is no common base type for those other than `Object`. The code would create an array of arrays if it worked, is that the result that you want?

Comment: @Guffa
Thanks for replying back. Yes i want assosiative array. All i want my DataTables to show data right now.. And i think it is not showing data cuz it is getting data in objects.

Comment: @Guffa You are right, but problem still persist, i tried function Convert.ToString() but got another error. That new [] did worked but i think its not converting, updating my question.

Comment: This solved my problem , your awesome! :D ! I'm using dataTables too

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not valid JSON. You could create it using string concatenation, but it would not be possible to parse it as JSON.

If you want to produce something that is possible to parse as JSON you need to follow the syntax rules.

If you want a collection of keys and values, you use an object:

```
{"CategoryID":1,"Name":"Computers","SortOrder":1}
```

If you use an array you only have values, no keys:

```
[1,"Computers",1]
```

Comment: what should i do then? i also tried to remove error by one more way, i updated my question.

Comment: @SizzlingCode: No matter how you try to create an object or array, you will never be able to produce the result that you expected. There are no combination of objects that can be serialised into that invalid JSON. If you really want to produce the invalid JSON, you have to do it by creating the string yourself.

Comment: Sir, Its ok if i get Values only and not keys. But how would i achieve it then that give me array not object.

Comment: You can try to make an array of objects, that's the only way to have an array with integers and strings in C#: `new object[] { c.CategoryID.ToString(), c.Name, c.SortOrder.ToString() }`

Comment: Yes. Thankyou. it didnt worked right away it gave me this error.
`The array type 'System.Object[]' cannot be initialized in a query result. Consider using 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' instead.`
But i searched google back again and found 1 fix for it.
I kind of had to call two queries, Updating my answer just in a moment.

Comment: updated my answer, it gives me the result i want but i am not sure if this is a good way to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. After many tries i finally got the result somehow in arrays rather then in objects.

Many Thanks to `@Guffa` Also as He helped Alot in Fixing my Problem.

He Finally gave the reply

```
new object[] { c.CategoryID.ToString(), c.Name, c.SortOrder.ToString() }
```

Which should have solved my problem but for some reason asp.net LINQ is not supporting .ToString() functions and i did got this error.

```
The array type 'System.Object[]' cannot be initialized in a query result. Consider using 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Object]' instead.
```

I am not good in ASP.NET MVC specially with Databases and C# so i start back to googeling.

I think i had to call query two times.

first result is converted `ToList()` ToList i think supports the ToString Function.

```
var categories = (from category in allCategories
              select category).ToList();
```

Then here when returning Json i wrote the query back again but here i used the Categories from First Query and then .ToString was working.

```
return Json(new
{
    sEcho = param.sEcho,
    iTotalRecords = allCategories.Count(),
    iTotalDisplayRecords = allCategories.Count(),
    aaData = (from category in categories
              select new [] {category.CategoryID.ToString(), category.Name, category.SortOrder.ToString()}).ToArray()
},
```

It gave me the result i wanted but i am not sure if this is the right way. What should be the Professional way or good way to have a secure and quick response controller. As i don't want to make a mess of my Code.

Comment: That looks fine. To keep the query out of the return value, you can write it as one query (or two queries in one) by using `ToList` to realise the result and then `Select` to work on the result as objects: `var categories = (from category in allCategories select category).ToList().Select(c => new[]{ c.CategoryID.ToString(), c.Name, c.SortOrder.ToString() });`.